# solution verification || Show that there are at least 946 subsets of M for which the sum of their elements is a natural number.

Tags: solution-verification, square-numbers

**Question**

The set is considered

$$M= {\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} ,..., \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2022}+\sqrt{2023}} }$$

Show that there are at least 946 subsets of M for which the sum of their elements is a natural number.

**My idea**

First of all, I observed that all the numbers in the set have the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a+1}}=\sqrt{a+1}-\sqrt{a}$ which will make the set:

$$M={\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}, \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}, ..., \sqrt{2023}-\sqrt{2022}$$

between $\sqrt{1}$ and $\sqrt{2023}$ there are 44 perfect squares, which means 44 elements of M are the difference between a natural number and an irrational number.

My idea is that if we make a subset that has any two of these 44 elements and the elements between them the sum of the elements of this subset would be a natural number. (*)

So we can make at least $44*43:2=946$ subsets of M for which the sum of their elements is a natural number.

Can you tell me if my solution is ok? If yes, can you help me explain better (*) part?

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: The (*) part is poorly explained (even though I know what you're going for), in part because of the prior statement "which means 44 elements of M are the difference between a natural number and an irrational number". That's because for each natural number, you're using different elements depending on whether we want to add or subtract it. EG To get $2 -1$, we use $(\sqrt{4} - \sqrt{3} ) + (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} ) + (\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{1} )$. Whereas, to get $ 3 - 2$, we use $(\sqrt{9} - \sqrt{8} ) + ... + ( \sqrt{ 5} - \sqrt{4} ) $. $\quad$ Also, don't be afraid of adding clear specific examples.

Comment: IMO the (*) part may be explained with a reference to the proof that no sums of algebraic numbers will result in natural numbers. In addition the task was to find _"at least 946"_, so the rest does not matter ;)